# how can i see the stack trace after the process is killed?

Tags: c, linux, gdb

i am using gdb command "attach" to debug a proceess
but after the process crash (sigkill) i can not see the stack trace ("bt" command in gdb) :
(gdb) bt
No stack.

how can i see the stack trace after the process is killed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set your shell to dump core by making sure `ulimit -c` doesn't show a core size of 0.  If it does say 0 then run `ulimit -c unlimited`. Next, re-run your program until it crashes and dumps core then call:

`gdb /path/to/executable /path/to/core` and type `bt` to get the stack trace.

Also, you'll want to compile your executable with debugging info turned on. If you're using `gcc` then I would suggest you use `-ggdb3` to do this.

Comment: You can even modify the File: /etc/sysctl.conf  : variable:
kernel.core_pattern = /tmp/core(Core File Path)  to set the core file PATH